# JQuery Bootstrap selectpicker show optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

here is the demo

```
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple name="selectpickerdemo"
      id="selectpickerdemo"> 
    <optgroup label="Label 1">
      <option value='a'>a</option>
      <option value='b'>b</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Label 2">
      <option value='c'>c</option>
      <option value='d'>d</option>
    </optgroup> 
  </select>
```

when i use selectpicker and choose one or more options,
  it shows like `a,b` or `a,c,d`
 i want to show like 
  `Label1-a,b` or `Label1-a,Label2-c,d`

thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectpicker', function() {
  var SelectedValues = [];
  $(this).find('optgroup').each(function() {
    var OptionGroupSelected = [];
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('selected')) {
        OptionGroupSelected.push($(this).val());
      }
    });
    if (OptionGroupSelected.length > 0) {
      var Label = $(this).attr('label').replace(' ', '');
      SelectedValues.push(Label + '-' + OptionGroupSelected.join(','));
    }
  });
  console.log(SelectedValues);
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46mfqusr/)

Comment: it works,thx !  i want the selectpicker label shows  Label1-a,b  and i use {$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('val',SelectedValues);  .but nothing change,is there any solution？

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but if my answer solved the original question, please make sure to mark the question as answered.